# Listbox highlight only when pressed

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am creating a Delphi XE6 Firemonkey mobile application and want to highlight a listbox item but only while it is being pressed. For an example of the effect I am after, create a new Firemonkey desktop application, add a TListBox and add the following event handlers and code:-

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
i: Integer;
begin  
//populate the listbox
for i := 0 to 19 do
ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1ItemClick(const Sender: TCustomListBox;
const Item: TListBoxItem);
begin
ListBox1.ItemIndex:=-1;
end;
```

Now click an item in the listbox and the highlight should disappear on release of the mouse button. Repeating the exercise for mobile sees only a long press producing the desired result and a short press causes the highlight to remain. So I dropped a timer on the form, setting enabled to FALSE, an interval of 200 and creating an OnTimer event:-

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
i: Integer;
begin  
//populate the listbox
for i := 0 to 19 do
ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBox1ItemClick(const Sender: TCustomListBox;
const Item: TListBoxItem);
begin
Timer1.Enabled:=TRUE;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox1.ItemIndex:=-1;
Timer1.Enabled:=FALSE;
end;
```

Progress is made but by rapid pressing of the listbox it is easily possible for the listbox to remain highlighted. I tried the timer option on a TListView and it appears to work as hoped but I'm eager to find a solution for TListBox.

Next brainwave was to add a button to the listboxitem:-

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
BoxItem: TListBoxItem;
ListBoxSpeedButton: TSpeedButton;

begin
for i := 0 to 99 do
 begin
 ListBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(i));
 BoxItem := ListBox1.ListItems[ListBox1.Items.Count-1];
 ListBoxSpeedButton:=TSpeedButton.Create(nil);
 ListBoxSpeedButton.Parent:=BoxItem;
 ListBoxSpeedButton.CanFocus:=FALSE;
 ListBoxSpeedButton.Align:=TAlignLayout.Client;
 end;
end;
```

However, when scrolling the listbox, the button gets activated and when using a custom Speedbutton, the scrolling is jerky and unresponsive and I can't help feeling I'm using controls when there is no need.

Is there a simple solution here?

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... I will start off by saying DONT USE listboxes when scrolling.... FMX Listboxes are meant to be stagnant and performance when scrolling is horrendous. Use a TListView and TListViewItems. There are tons of examples on SO and in the packaged Delphi XE6 examples on how to implement a list via TListView. That being said, there is no need for timers.. Make use of events already available to use for such things, such as OnMouseDown and onMouseUp which are events assigned to basically every FMX control ( ListBox ListBoxItem or ListView, etc.).... Tons of ways to go about implementing this...

Try this - setting onMouseDown and MouseUp events for every listboxItem to what you see below:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBoxItem5MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  if sender is TListboxItem then
    ListBox.ItemIndex:=TListBoxItem(sender).index
end;

procedure TForm1.ListBoxItem5MouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  ListBox.ItemIndex:=-1;
end;
```

Comment: Good point about the TListview but I am determined to know why this is not working on TListBox and am reluctant to admit that I have also grown fond of the way the group headers stack when scrolling the listbox, is that possible with ListView?

Comment: With ListBox1OnMouseDown event, sender is TListBox when selecting an item and always gives index=1? With sender as TListBox, ListBox1.ItemIndex always gives the value of the previous keypress, -1 wherever you click first. I even tried Form.OnMouseDown with ListBox Hittest to 0. The ListBoxItemClick event with sender as TCustomListBox and setting ListBox1.ItemIndex to -1 comes close but a short press keeps the item highlighted and only a longer press clears it. This is why I tried the TTimer idea. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Updated answer to be a bit more clear if I wasnt. Tested and it works for me. Note: there are different ways to 'highlight' an item whether it be setting the right properties for the listbox and setting desired ListBoxItem.selected = true or the way I have shown with Item Index in the example, which is also the way u initially tried. You can also access styled properties to change the items background color ( search SO if you want to know how to work with styles).

Comment: To answer the ListBox vs ListView question... yes, you can group items the same way with a Listview where they cascade together. The main differences between the two besides implementation is that: Listboxes are more customizable ( e.g., you can drop x amount of TTexts on a ListBoxItem where you can't on a TListViewItem) yet TListView scrolls *almost flawlessly no matter the amount of items where TListbox lags.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply but it is still not working for me. I had been using ListBox MouseDown and MouseUp events rather than ListBoxItem events so hopes were high but after a simple exercise of dropping a ListBox onto a form, adding 3 ListBoxItems and setting the MouseDown and MouseUp events to point to your code above, it is still not behaving as I want. Press an item for longer than a tap, hold then release and it works fine. However, briefly tap an item and where it should then flash briefly and disappear, unfortunately it remains highlighted. Testing on real phone with Jellybean 4.2.1

Comment: I've now uploaded a video to show this problem in action. Get it here for a short time: http://bit.ly/1tEuWpr The video shows a longer than tap press on all 3 items (works correctly) then a short tap on item2 (stays highlighted) then a normal press on item 3 followed by a quick tap (stays highlighted).

Comment: Getting there! On creation, each ListBoxItem has HitTest:=FALSE. Set each ListBoxItem HitTest property:=TRUE and it works as required. However, this has adversely affected scrolling performance insomuch that the listbox is now overly responsive and jerky. Any slight touch causes the listbox to highlight when you might want to just scroll the items. Consider the Call Log on android - scrolling up/down through the entries sees no selection made, just a nice fluid scroll. Positively make a selection and the highlight is then made, it almost knows what you want to do! How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hence why i said Listview>listbox when scrolling.

Comment: I have the same highlight issues with TListView too ThisGuy. The video shows the problem clearly but I also tried it on a ListView with the same result. You can also repeatedly tap an item and the highlight will always remain showing. That was before setting HitTest:=TRUE for each item though. But...

Comment: I am starting to think that maybe the hittest thing isn't right? It is super slow, almost jabbing your finger through the glass of the phone to start movement. But here's the thing - after a slow start and managing to scroll the items, it starts to speed up almost as if it's warming up before bursting into life! So, should HitTest be TRUE on all items in the listbox? If so, why are they set to FALSE by default? Also, if that is the case, the highlight should not happen when you are just scrolling. Refer to an android phone call log for what I mean. Any clues? Thanks for the help so far ThisGuy